# In Lua, how can you print the name of the current function, like the C99 __func__ identifier?

Tags: lua

Something like this:

```
function foo()
    print( __func__ )
   ...
end
```

How can it be done?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021816/in-lua-how-can-you-print-the-name-of-the-current-function-like-the-c99-func/4037184#4037184 for what I'm trying to achieve :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/lua

local function myFunc()
 print(debug.getinfo(1, "n").name);
end
myFunc()
```

Comment: This currently returns "nil" in Lua 5.3.

Answer (score 13):

You can't. In lua, functions are values. So they don't have names. You might as well ask "what the name of 2" is. Just because some variable was assigned the value '2' doesn't make that variable the name of 2. Likewise "someFunc" is a variable - potentially one of many - that holds a particular function.

---

As per @Orouborus in the comments:

`function f() end` is just syntactical sugar for `f = function () end`

Whatever you are doing, whatever the other posts are helping you do, you can print out the name of the thing on the left, "f", but not the name of the thing on the right.

Comment: how does your answer comply with the accepted answer?

Comment: It doesn't. Both answers are technically correct. If - by name - you want the unique unchanging assigned name of a lua function - what __FUNC__ provides for C programs - you can't get it. If by name you simply want the name of an variable that has the function as its value, use the debug methods to get that, remembering that variables can be reassigned, and multiple variables can contain the same value - so the "name" returned this way is neither unique nor unchanging.

Comment: In Lua, functions are _not_ variables. [They are _values_](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#2.1) that can be passed around.

Comment: First class citizen is not a valid reason to prevent access its name. For example, in Python, you can access it by `myFunc.__name__`. In JavaScript, it would be `myFunc.name`. But in C, after linking, there is nothing about function name for you. And we all know Python and JavaScript support first class function, but not C.

Comment: Afaik, `function f() end` is syntactical sugar for `f = function () end`. Lua functions don't have names. They can be assigned to variables, but the variable name isn't the function name.

Answer (score 8):

```
function __FILE__() return debug.getinfo(2, 'S').source end
function __LINE__() return debug.getinfo(2, 'l').currentline end
function __FUNC__() return debug.getinfo(2, 'n').name end

function printlinefilefunc()
    print("Line at "..__LINE__()..", FILE at "..__FILE__()..", in func: "..__FUNC__())
end
```

Output:

> Line at 8, FILE at @./andydebug.lua, in func: printlinefilefunc

Comment: Depends on lua interpretter / version. debug.getinfo(2, 'S').source gave me whole source code of .lua script.

Answer (score 4):

While I agree with [Ephraim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021816/in-lua-how-can-you-print-the-name-of-the-current-function-like-the-c99-func), that code will not always report the same name as pointed out by Chris Becke. When the function is assigned to another variable, the "name" would be changed.

Here is another alternative. It just uses a string to identify the function. This method solves the changing name problem, but introduces a maintenance issue. The string would need to be kept in sync with the function name with future refactorization.

```
function foo()
  local __func__ = "foo"
  print( __func__ )
  --...
end
```

Alternatively, if the location of the function is more important than the name, the following may be better. It will give a name to the function that is based on the source and line number.

```
function getfunctionlocation()
  local w = debug.getinfo(2, "S")
  return w.short_src..":"..w.linedefined
end

function foo()
  print(getfunctionlocation()) --> foo.lua:6
  --...
end
```

If the `__func__` still seems better, and standard Lua is not important, then the Lua parser can be modified as it is in [this example for `__FILE__` and `__LINE__`](http://lua-users.org/wiki/FileLineMacros).

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Debug Library](http://www.lua.org/pil/23.1.html). It provides a `getinfo(func)` function that returns a table with information about the function.

Answer (score 2):

Functions don't necessarily have them. It's perfectly legal in Lua to create anonymous functions with no name- and call it, without assigning it one.

```
(function()
    print("in anonymous function!")
end)()
```

Is perfectly valid Lua. What name do you want to give that function?

Comment: in stacktraces, these functions appear as `</path/to/filename.lua:$LINE>`, , where $LINE is the line where the function appears.

Comment: Not really answering the question

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
local dbFunc = debug.getinfo(1) and debug.getinfo(1).name or ""

Info
Info["currentline"] = 1376
Info["source"] = "@.\mymod.lua"
Info["short_src"] = ".\mymod.lua"
Info["nups"] = 13
Info["isvararg"] = false
Info["what"] = "Lua"
Info["lastlinedefined"] = 1570
Info["func"] = function: 000000000030B440
Info["istailcall"] = false
Info["linedefined"] = 1375
Info["namewhat"] = "field"
Info["name"] = "ExportDB" <<--- See here the function name
Info["nparams"] = 4
```

`debug.getinfo(1)` Returns this structure of the current execution state of the active function in the stack.

If n is larger than the number of active functions in the stack, `debug.getinfo()` returns nil.

That's why you have to check if it exists before taking *.name and return an empty string if the information is not available

A it is called inside the `ExportDB()` function, it return its name

Comment: Minor note (yes, I know this is an old thread): using `debug.getinfo(1) or ""` will work the same as `debug.getinfo(1) and debug.getinfo(1) or ""`

Comment: Why Did you vote down when you know it. I am just trying to help you ??!!

Comment: 1) This was two and a half years ago. 2) I didn’t downvote, someone else did.