# How can I get a function's name by its pointer in Lua?

Tags: debugging, function, lua

In Lua I've created a pretty printer for my tables/objects.  However, when a function is displayed, it's shown as a pointer.

I've been reading up on [Lua Introspection](http://www.lua.org/pil/23.1.html) but when I introspect the function with `debug.getinfo()` it won't return the function's name.  This seems to be due to a scoping issue but I'm not sure how to get around it.

What is the best way to get a function's name using its pointer?  (I understand functions are first class citizens in Lua and that they can be created anonymously, that's fine)

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021816/

Comment: I was hoping to do it without having to actually modify the functions. I wanted to get the function name for my table printer.

Answer (score 4):

when you create the functions, register them in a table, using them as keys.

```
local tableNames = {}

function registerFunction(f, name)
  tableNames[f] = name
end

function getFunctionName(f)
  return tableNames[f]
end

...
function foo()
  ..
end
registerFunction(foo, "foo")
...

getFunctionName(foo) -- will return "foo"
```

Comment: @Soviut I was going to respond with something like this too. Teeeeechnically speaking, Lua functions do not have names. When you enter `function foo()`, it is the same as doing `foo = function()`. In other words, the function is a free agent that just happens to have a variable named `foo` pointing to it.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, it seems to work only with number parameters (that is, active functions on the stack).

The script

```
function a() return debug.getinfo(1,'n') end
function prettyinfo(info) 
    for k,v in pairs(info) do print(k,v) end
end
prettyinfo(a())
```

prints

```
name    a
namewhat    global
```

but if I change the last line to

```
prettyinfo(debug.getinfo(a, 'n'))
```

it gives me only an empty string:

```
namewhat
```